# Dart: Error parsing JSON with nested json embedded in string

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having issue with the below code, the following code failed to parse the given json:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String jsonString = '''
    {
      "status": "success",
      "data":{
        "edit": 1,
        "draft": "{\"id\":\"25863\",\"type\":\"ABC\"}"
      }
    }
  ''';

    try{
    var decode = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    print(decode);
  }on FormatException catch(e){
    print('error ${e.toString()}');
  }
}
```

The error I am getting:

> error FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 6, character 31)

Also I have used `jsonDecode(jsonEncode(jsonString))`, but that's does not meet my requirements as I require the data as Map<String, dynamic>. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the JSON string that you have entered here is correct? are we passing `'''` something like this with the JSON String?

Comment: Yes it's correct, that's how I receive from the API, thing is theres a json string embedded inside the root json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have to change this to  `"draft": "{\"id\":\"25863\",\"type\":\"ABC\"}"` this `"draft": {\"id\":\"25863\",\"type\":\"ABC\"}` by removing this `"` between json will do it. but you have to make sure your api response will be same formate

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var jsonString = '''{
      "status": "success",
      "data": {
        "edit": 1,
        "draft": "{\"id\":\"25863\",\"type\":\"ABC\"}"
      }
    }''';
  String purifiedJsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(r'"{', '{').replaceAll(r'}"', '}');


  print(purifiedJsonString);
  var result=  jsonDecode(purifiedJsonString);
  print(result);
  print(result['data']['draft']);
}
```

Comment: How can I get return Map<String,dynamic> in that case when applying jsonDecode?

Comment: then some how we have to purify the `draft` data to json right?

Comment: Yes, we need to purify it.

Comment: i have edited the code can you try it? by adding `r` in front of the string

Comment: Yes that works, but how can I do that when I get it as API response?

Comment: if you receive it from API then converting in to rawstring not going to work i think. we have to purify the draft. let me edit my answer again

Comment: Your updated code works, I think it can be full proof if we go with regex, I will try to add that approach. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `\` too much at the draft line at the end. Also you need to escape the \ with another \ if you want to use backslashes in a string definition.

```
  String jsonString = '''
    {
      "status": "success",
      "data":{
        "edit": 1,
        "draft": "{\\"id\\":\\"25863\\",\\"type\\":\\"ABC\\"}"
      }
    }
  ''';
```

But it is kind of strange that you let the "draft" field be another JSON string. It would make more sense as this and I think you should use this:

```
  String jsonString = '''
    {
      "status": "success",
      "data":{
        "edit": 1,
        "draft": {
          "id": "25863",
          "type": "ABC"
        }
      }
    }
  ''';
```

Comment: I have copied the api response, yes its weird, but that's how it is, I have to use and parse it as it is.

Comment: well, the `jsonString` as it is written in your question is simply not valid JSON

Comment: Every online json validator returns this as valid.

Comment: I mean isn't there should be a way that it could accept the embedded json as string?

Comment: @aaa111 I mean you edited to a valid JSON now, by leaving out the last backslash.  Then you can get your draft as map by doing `var draft = jsonDecode(decode['data']['draft'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
String jsonString = '
  {
  "status": "success",
  "data":{
    "edit": 1,
    "draft": "{\"id\":\"25863\",\"type\":\"ABC\"}"
  }
}
';
 Data jsonData = Data.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));
 print(jsonData);
 print(jsonData['data']['draft']);
```

}

It is better to follow architecture. So, don't forget to create model and then use this code. Create model of the `Data` class first after then pass the json converted String to the model. with the use of model you can easily get an error message if you use wrong dataType other by default it will convert int to String as well.